# How to convert CString to wchar_t

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Any one can help to convert `CString` to `wchar_t`?

```
String csFileName = "";

csFileName.Format("D:\\test\\test %d.jpg", nFile); nFile += 1;


wchar_t *messageArray = static_cast< wchar_t *>(csFileName); wchar_t
firstCharacter = csFileName[0]; ImageFileParams.pwchFileName =
(wchar_t *)(&csFileName);
```

Answer (score 4):

`CString` is defined as `CStringW` in case `UNICODE` is enabled. So you can use it as is. It does implement cast operator `LPCWSTR` -> `const wchar*`

In case of MBCS `CString` is defined as `CStringA`. In this case you can simply do stuff like:

```
CStringA str = "Hello";
CStringW wideStr = str;
```

That's it.

Here are handy conversion utilities:

```
// UTF8 conversion
CStringA CUtility::UTF16toUTF8(const CStringW& utf16)
{
    return CW2A(utf16, CP_UTF8);
}

CStringW CUtility::UTF8toUTF16(const CStringA& utf8)
{
    return CA2W(utf8, CP_UTF8);
}
```

Comment: hii thnks @Andrew Komiagin for your reply can you please provide me revised code. I still can't understand.. I am new in C++

Comment: pls help for better understanding

Comment: CString csFileName;
csFileName.Format(_T("D:\\test\\test %d.jpg"), nFile); 
nFile++;
ImageFileParams.pwchFileName = const_cast<wchar_t*>(LPCTSTR)csFileName;

Comment: Make sure the project is configured to use UNICODE.

Comment: hii thnx for reply but  type name not allowed error for "(LPCTSTR)"                                  &      expecting a ':'error for "csFileName"

Comment: This one compiles just fine: ImageFileParams.pwchFileName   = const_cast<wchar_t*>((LPCTSTR)csFileName);

Comment: hii thnks @ andrew komiagin it is still showing error for  '((LPCTSTR)csFileName);' Error: a const_cast can only adjust type qualifiers ; cannot change underlying type ......

Comment: that's weird. I've just compiled it just fine. Are you using MSVC and UNICODE char set?

Answer (score 1):

For a cross-platform solution, you can use [utf8rewind](https://bitbucket.org/knight666/utf8rewind):

```
std::wstring towide(const std::string& text)
{
    std::wstring converted;
    int32_t errors;

    size_t size_in_bytes = utf8towide(text.c_str(), text.length(), nullptr, 0, &errors);
    if (size_in_bytes == 0 ||
        errors != UTF8_ERR_NONE)
    {
        return converted;
    }

    converted.resize(size_in_bytes);
    utf8towide(text.c_str(), text.length(), &converted[0], size_in_bytes, nullptr);

    return converted;
}

std::string toansi(const std::wstring& text)
{
    std::string converted;
    int32_t errors;

    size_t size_in_bytes = widetoutf8(text.c_str(), text.length(), nullptr, 0, &errors);
    if (size_in_bytes == 0 ||
        errors != UTF8_ERR_NONE)
    {
        return converted;
    }

    converted.resize(size_in_bytes);
    widetoutf8(text.c_str(), text.length(), &converted[0], size_in_bytes, nullptr);

    return converted;
}
```

Comment: hii can you please provide example in form of my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
std::wstring StringToWString(const std::string & s)
{
    std::wstring temp(s.length(),L' ');
    std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), temp.begin());
    return temp; 
}
```

and in reverse:

```
std::string WCharBuf2String(WCHAR* wchar_buf)
{
    char narrow_buf[260];
    char DefChar = ' ';
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wchar_buf, -1, narrow_buf, 260, &DefChar, NULL);
    return std::string (narrow_buf);
}
```

Comment: hii can you please provide example in form of my code ?